# Solving the Diophantine equation $y^2 = x^4+x+ 2$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to solve the Diophantine equation $y^2 = x^4+x+ 2$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I already found 4 solutions: $(x,y) = (1,\pm2)$ and $(x,y)=(-2,\pm4)$. It can probably be solved using some factorization argument, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\geq -1$, then $$x^4<y^2<(x^2+2)^2\,.$$
Therefore, for $x\geq -1$, there exists a solution iff $x^4+x+2=(x^2+1)^2$.  The only integer root of the last equation is $x=1$, yielding the solutions $(x,y)=(1,\pm2)$.

If $x\leq -3$, then $$(x^2-2)^2<y^2<x^4\,.$$
Therefore, for $x\leq -3$, there exists a solution iff $x^4+x+2=(x^2-1)^2$.  The last equation does not have an integer root, whence there does not exist a solution in this case.

If $x=-2$, then we have the solutions $(x,y)=(-2,\pm 4)$.  Therefore, there are only four solutions $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to $y^2=x^4+x+2$, which are $(1,\pm2)$ and $(-2,\pm4)$.

Comment: Can you further explain the statement: there exists a solution iff $x^4+x+2=(x^2+1)^2$?

Comment: You have a square $y^2$ lying strictly between two squares $a^2$ and $(a+2)^2$ (here, $a:=x^2$), then surely, $y^2$ is the square in the middle: $(a+1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "simple method" to solve the Diophantine equation
$$
Y^2=X^4+aX^3+bX^2+cX+d
$$
in general, see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwjCi_TsvI7fAhUFQhoKHSGODCgQFjADegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ems-ph.org%2Fjournals%2Fshow_pdf.php%3Fissn%3D0013-6018%26vol%3D54%26iss%3D1%26rank%3D4&usg=AOvVaw3WH9KxfDcc13Oa_JdIKwcl). The second section does it for the example of $Y^2=X^4-8X^2+8X+1$, but $Y^2=X^4+X+2$ should be even easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Would you know how to find the bounds on the solutions, without using this theorem? Just for this specific case? Because this theorem is a bit of an overkill, and not something I could remember during an exam..

Comment: Diophantine equations are not for exams. They are for pleasure!

Comment: I wonder what grade I get if I write that on the exam :p